# How to upcast collection in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have some types:

```scala
abstract class TransitionalState
class State extends TransitionalState
class Parallel extends TransitionalState
```

and their wrappers:

```scala
trait TransitionalStateWrapper[T <: TransitionalState]  {
  def state: T
}
trait StateWrapper extends TransitionalStateWrapper[State]
trait ParallelWrapper extends TransitionalStateWrapper[Parallel]
```

Then I have method:

```
 def convert(): List[TransitionalStateWrapper[TransitionalState]] = {
    val list: List[StateWrapper] = List(new StateWrapper {
      def state: State = new State {}
    })
    list
  }
```

How I can upcast `list` to `List[TransitionalStateWrapper[TransitionalState]]`?

I got `Error:(18, 5) type mismatch;
 found   : List[StateWrapper]
 required: List[TransitionalStateWrapper[TransitionalState]]
    list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upcast it because `TransitionalStateWrapper[State]` is not a subtype of `TransitionalStateWrapper[TransitionalState]`.

`TransitionalStateWrapper` would have to be covariant in type parameter `T`.

```
trait TransitionalStateWrapper[+T <: TransitionalState]  {
  def state: T
}
```